# Rails 4 query a reference via n:n relation

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

following structure

```
  Production
  belongs_to :offer
  has_many :production_positions
  has_many :products, through: :production_positions

  Product
  has_many :production_positions
  has_many :productions, through: :production_positions

  ProductionPosition
  belongs_to :production
  belongs_to :product
```

Now i want to get all offers which contains the product_id 1. How did i have to query the database?

To get the productions is quite easy:

```
  Production.includes(:products).where("products.id" => 1)
```

but how do i get the offers which are referenced?

```
 Offer.includes(:production).includes(:products).where("products.id" => 1)
```

the line above produces the following error:
Association named 'products' was not found on Offer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `has_many :products, through: :production` in your `Offer` class and try with the following:

```
Offer.select('offers.*').joins(:products).where('products.id = ?', 1)
```

I assumed you had `has_one :production` in your `Offer` class. You could add a scope to perform the query:

```
class Offer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :production
  has_many :products, through: :production

  scope :with_product_id, ->(id) do
    select('offers.*').
      joins(:products). 
      where('products.id = ?', id)
  end
end
```

Example (Offers with Product 1):

```
Offer.with_product_id(1)
```

Comment: thx, but still the same: Association named 'products' was not found on Offer